# How fix the error :invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Luck'?

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, variables, exception

The code below is what is used in my coursework. At the moment the line "if int(what_skill) < 0 or int(what_skill) > 9:" is producing the error above. I have tried changing it to a str() however this produces another error.

def player():

```
vigor = 1

endurance = 1

strength = 1

dexterity = 1

intelligence = 1

luck = 1
points = 25
while points !=0:
    what_skill = input("What skill would you like to add to? Vigor, Endurance, Strength, Dexterity, Intelligance, Luck? ")
    print(what_skill)
    add_points = int(input("You have " + str(points) + " points left. How many points from 1-9 would you like to add to " + str(what_skill) + "? "))


    if int(add_points) > 9:
        print("Too many points")
        print(add_points)
    else:
        if int(what_skill) < 0 or int(what_skill) > 9:
            print("invaid choice")
        else:
            update_skill = int(what_skill) + int(add_points)
            points = points - add_points
```

Comment: "Luck" is a String -- it doesnt make sense that you're trying to convert it to an int

Comment: `what_skill` is skill **name**, your point value is `add_points`, so `int(what_skill)` will obviously break the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing the error is because of the lines

```
int(what_skill)
```

In your example, this equates to

```
int("luck")
```

Which doesnt make any sense --- I think you're trying to do `int(luck)` -- to reference the number inside the variable

I would change your skills to a dictionary and use something like the following:

```
stats = {
  "Luck": 1,
  "Vigor": 1,
  "Endurance": 1,
  "Strength": 1,
  "Dexterity": 1,
  "Intelligence" : 1
}

points = 25
while points >= 1:
    what_skill = input("What skill would you like to add to? Vigor, Endurance, Strength, Dexterity, Intelligance, Luck? ")
    add_points = int(input("You have " + str(points) + " points left. How many points from 1-9 would you like to add to " + str(what_skill) + "? "))

    if int(add_points) > 9:
        print("Too many points")
    else:
        if stats[what_skill] < 0 or stats[what_skill] > 9:
            print("invalid choice")
        else:
            update_skill = stats[what_skill] + int(add_points)
            points = points - add_points
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because `what_skill` is of string type, and by type casting, you cannot convert a word to integer. `int('abc')` would result in the same error you're facing.

If you want to refer to the variables you've initialized at the start, use a dictionary instead, with key being the skill, and the values being the respective points. Now, you can access the points as `myDict[what_skill]`. Using dictionary is so far the most efficient solution.